# over ..., over the course of ..., etc. - interchangeable?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Are these sentences correct? Is there any difference in meaning?

*The situation has changed dramatically **over the course of the last two years**.*

*The situation has changed dramatically **in the course of the last two years**.*

*The situation has changed dramatically **over the last two years**.*

*The situation has changed dramatically **in the last two years**.*

*The situation has changed dramatically **within the last two years**.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Oxford Dictionary makes no distinction](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_(or_over)_the_course_of_time) between 'in' or 'over' in this context, so either is acceptable.  There is little to no distinction between 'in the course' and 'over the course', but the latter may be used to describe a more gradual change in events.

The different versions are more a question of formality, since it may be more appropriate to use 'over the course' in a formal/business setting, but when used informally can sound wrong.  This is a matter of opinion though, and it's up to the user to decide what they will use.

'Within the last two years' may be used to describe a situation which has since changed for the better or worse, for example:

> My health has improved within the last two years

which implies that previously it was going downhill, or

> The financial situation has changed dramatically within the last 10 years

which could be used to mean that previously it was improving.